# My ASP.NET Web Application cannot 'find' any of my classes in the App_Code folder ..?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, app-code

I'm trying to make a new asp.net web application .. so I'm copying my files from one site to the new one, in the same solution.

Now, any of my classes in the `App_Code` directory ... they are not getting 'picked up' by the rest of my project.

For example...

```
\_
\_App_Code
  |_ BaseMasterPage.cs  (please don't ask why this is in here..)
  |_ Utility.cs
  |_ FooBar.cs
\_MasterPages
  |_ Default.master.cs

// This file errors ;(
namespace Foo.WebSite.MasterPages
{
    public partial class Default_master : App_Code.BaseMasterPage
    { ... }
}

namespace Foo.WebSite.App_Code
{
    public class BaseMasterPage : MasterPage
    { .. }
}
```

It cannot find the `App_Code.BaseMasterPage` (compilation and intellisence error) in the `Default.master.cs` page.

I'm wondering if there's something i need to check in a web.config file? or in the .prj file or something?

Can someone please help? this is killing me :(

#### Update

I've been constantly trying more and more things here. I had a look at the compiler options (in the OUTPUT window) .. and noticed the /target flag, on the compiler call...

```
eg...
/target:library App_GlobalResources\GlobalResources.designer.cs
    App_GlobalResources\GlobalResources.en-au.designer.cs
    App_GlobalResources\GlobalResources.it.designer.cs
```

etc...

it's missing ALL of my .cs files from the App_Code folder, except two, which I can confirm show up in the intellisence and compile fine, when called/consumed.

WTF? it's like the .. project .. doesn't know about the other .cs files, even though they have been included into the project (and are not grey'd out, etc).

What the?!

Please, can anyone help ? :~(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several guesses :

try replacing  the namespace

```
   namespace Foo.WebSite.MasterPages 
     {
       public partial class Default_master :
   Foo.WebSite.App_Code.BaseMasterPage
       { ... } 
      }
```

or/and Have a look at the properties of the file in VS, make
   sure they are not embedded ressource
   or something of the kind.

last thing have a look at the default namespace in your application

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've given that a go and still no luck :( ... BUT ... I then checked if they were Embedded Resources .. which they were not. They were ALL *Content* (which is bad!!) You did it! Except the two classes that were compiling (which were set to Compile), I then quickly updated all the files to *COMPILE* and viola .. we are building again. Thank you kind sir! :)

Comment: The properties page seems to have been removed in VS 2019?!

Answer (score 15):

In the solution explorer, right click on the class.cs file, view it's properties and set the build action to 'compile' instead of 'content'

Comment: This worked for me too, this is certainly the answer (or a very commonly accepted answer) to the problem described.